# After Effects rendering wrong colors?

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I'm creating a video using After Effects CC 2015 for use it on a website.
The background of the page on the site is `#607D8B`, so the first thing I did was create a solid with that color, and the color was right, however when I rendered, the color changed to `#6e8995`.
What are the settings I need to do to avoid this problem? I exported using Adobe Media Encoder and the standard H264.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a color space / range flag or rendering issue. Quickest way to resolve this is to take a short screencast i.e. video capture of the page. Load that into After Effects and pick that color. You can't take a screnshot. It has to be a video. OBS, ffmpeg, VLC, Screenflow, Camtasia..etc can all screen-record.

Answer (score 1):

As Mulvya says - it sounds like a color space export issue..

See this previous answer - [Color shift after exporting!](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13174/color-shift-after-exporting/13192#13192)

I think this could be to do with "color space". I've had similar issues with exporting videos from After Effects. Exporting using "REC 709" Color space usually gives me the colours I expect. You can read more about how Adobe handle different Color spaces here:

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/aftereffects/articles/color_management_workflow/ae_color_mgmt_wkflow.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Mov output came exact color. what we're expected.
please check below image.

[image]

If you want you can use mov output instead of H.264 mp4 output.

Please check your project color settingss. Keep default settings
[image]

Go to Composition->Add to Render Queue->Lossless.

Change Format default AVI to Quicktime.
Please check below image[image]

Keep color management also default setting.
[image]

Then Press Ok to get output.

Check now